# Basis for the compositum of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $L/K,L'/K$ be field extensions and $\alpha,\beta$ be $K$-bases for $L,L'$ respectively.
>
> Define $A:=\{xy: x\in\alpha, y\in\beta\}$.
>
> How do I prove that $LL'=\mathrm{span}_K(A)$?

I could show that $\mathrm{span}_K(A)$ is closed under multiplication and addition and it contains $L\cup L'$.

However, I am stuck at showing that $\mathrm{span}_K(A)$ is closed under the inverse map. That is, how do I prove that $1/x\in \mathrm{span}_K(A)$ for a nonzero $x\in \mathrm{span}_K(A)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does $LL'$ mean?  Are they both subfields of an even bigger field?

Comment: @RobertLewis  Yes{}{}{{

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is false.  For instance, suppose $L=K(x)$ and $L'=K(y)$ as subfields of the field of rational functions $K(x,y)$.  Then $\operatorname{span}_K(A)$ is the set of rational functions of the form $\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)h(y)}$.  This is not a field: for instance, it contains $x+y$ but does not contain $\frac{1}{x+y}$.

On the other hand, it is true if either $L$ or $L'$ is algebraic over $K$.  Indeed, suppose that $L$ is algebraic over $K$.  Then every element of $L$ is algebraic over $L'$ since $K\subseteq L'$.  Hence every element of $\operatorname{span}_K(A)$ is also algebraic over $L'$, since every such element is an $L'$-linear combination of elements of $L$.  Thus if $x\in \operatorname{span}_K(A)$ is nonzero, $L'[x]=L'(x)$ and in particular $1/x\in L'[x]$.  But $L'[x]\subseteq\operatorname{span}_K(A)$ since $\operatorname{span}_K(A)$ is closed under addition and multiplication, so $1/x\in\operatorname{span}_K(A)$.